# How to pass value of a selected row in a popup div(which contains php include another file) on click of a button?

Tags: php

I have a form in which all the contacts are listed with fields like first name last name etc. Every row has view edit delete anchor tags on which I am calling a popup div. This popup div contains the php include(external file). I want to access the selected rows unique database primary key in that external file. 
The link of the code is 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/88qpmkwmaepa5s4/New%20Text%20Document%20%283%29.txt

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: If you could provide some output that would be a great help to fix your issue

Comment: When I click on view edit or delete button a popup opens with the external php file that I have included. My question is how do I access the selected row value(database) from that included file

Comment: If the pop up is a window pop up you can send it via the url of the popup which needs `&row=the_value` can be concatenated with the popup URL. If the popup is a div which you open it you get the id by javascript; for example you can have the id in the row as attribute and onClick of the row you can select the row and pass the value by javascript

Comment: Its not a window popup. Its a div popup and I am able to get id through java script but how do I pass it to that div( php included file). This is where I m stuck

Comment: OK, now you need to pass it by Ajax; I will provide a sample as solution below for you. Are you using jquery?

Comment: I just used a simple javascript function to change divs display to block. I had the same idea like doing in with ajax but couldnt get it working.

Comment: I provided the sample. If you just want to change the divs display to block why do you need the php file and passing the id of the selected row? I cannot understand this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple example to call Ajax by javascript and send the clicked row id to the php file, check this

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         //returned response from ajax to the php page will be in xmlhttp.responseText
         alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // Do whatever you need with the respones
      }
   }
   var selected_row = document.getElementById('selected_row').innerText; // we assume this is the value of the selected row 
   xmlhttp.open("GET","path_to_your_phpfile&row_id=" + encodeURIComponent(selected_row), true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Now the selected row id is passed by GET and in your php file you can get by `$row_id = $_GET['row_id'];`

Comment: I tried using window.alert and its showing the right values but when I try to access it in my popup div page it says undefined index. The code is used is https://www.dropbox.com/s/88qpmkwmaepa5s4/New%20Text%20Document%20%283%29.txt

Comment: Change your url to `"view_details.php?row_id=" + encodedURIComponent(selected_row)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you go for a quick kill with AJAX.

Javascript:

```
<script>
function show_div(id) {
function show_lightbox(){
// your code
}
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "get_detail.php",
data: "id=" + id,
dataType: "html",
success: function(html){
       $("#show_detail").html(html);     
       }
}); 
}
</script>
```

Html:

```
 <div id="lightbox">
   <div id="show_detail"></div>
   </div>
```

In your anchors:

```
<a onClick="show_div(uniqe_primarykey)">Click to fetch details</a>
```

In get_details.php

```
 <?php
   $id = $_POST[id];
   //your queries
   ?>

   <html>
   Data from queries
   </html>
```